# Consolidation of intervals

Tags: perl, awk, intervals, bioinformatics

I'm working with biological data (copy number variations) which is shown as intervals (tab separated file):

File 1

```
Columns: Chromosome, Start, End, Annotation

1   1   10  A
1   3   12  B
1   7   15  C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E
1   37  45  F
1   50  60  G
1   50  65  H
```

I intersected them in order to consolidate the overlapping events (50% of overlap is my condition), the result is this:

I used intersectBed from Bedtools (http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html):

```
 $ intersectBed -a File1 -b File1 -loj -f 0.50 -r > File 2
```

File 2

```
Columns: Chromosome, Start, End, Annotation , Chromosome, Start, End, Annotation

    1       1       10      A       1       1       10      A
    1       1       10      A       1       3       12      B
    1       3       12      B       1       1       10      A
    1       3       12      B       1       3       12      B
    1       3       12      B       1       7       15      C
    1       7       15      C       1       3       12      B
    1       7       15      C       1       7       15      C
    1       20      30      D       1       20      30      D
    1       35      45      E       1       35      45      E
    1       35      45      E       1       37      45      F
    1       37      45      F       1       35      45      E
    1       37      45      F       1       37      45      F
    1       50      60      G       1       50      60      G
    1       50      60      G       1       50      65      H
    1       50      65      H       1       50      60      G
    1       50      65      H       1       50      65      H
```

Event A and the event C overlaps with the event B, event E and F overlaps with each other like G and H, finally the event D has no overlapping partners. Knowing this, the list of consolidated CNV should be:

File 3

```
1    1  15 A,B,C
1   20  30 D
1   35  45 E,F
1   50  65 G,H
```

I was trying to use the merge option of the HDCNV java software (http://daleylab.org/lab/?page_id=125) but the output is not what I needed. I was trying to write a perl code but I'm a beginner so this problem is, at the moment, out of my limits.

I would appreciate if you can help me with a nice perl or awk code which take File 2 as input and outputs File 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to do the second step (generating file 2)? It seems that you could get the results in file 3 straight from file one. Also, are the letters assigned alphabetically to a sorted data set - i.e. the numbers in column 2 will always be sorted? Does the first column have any significance?

Comment: @ialarmedalien: I guess you could, but it seems the tool he is using does some extra stuff (for example, note that `A` and `C` don't overlap because of a setting on his tool: I don't know if it does anything else).

Comment: Yep, I agree with @Amadan. Looking at the first file, `A`, `B` and `C` don't overlap.

Comment: I assume that the columns mean ??, start, end, identifier. If so, A, B, and C would overlap - A is 1-10, B is 3-12, C is 7-15. The whole region covered by A,B,C is therefore 1-15. Oh, I do like a mysterious, badly-explained data set!

Comment: @ialarmedalien `:)`. That would make them _not_ overlap. Looking at `E` and `F` with `E` starting at `35` and ending at `45` and `F` from `37` to `45` making it `E`'s subset. Same with `G` and `H`. I think I just lost my sleep for tonight.

Comment: @jaypal Your interp doesn't make sense given the output that the OP wants. Perhaps it would be better if the OP actually explained what the columns mean, rather than us trying to guess!

Comment: Not sure what is not clear (aside from the mysterious `1` column): Gather names that cooccur in file2 and take their minimum `from` and maximum `to`.

Comment: The key is the parenthesized "(50% of overlap)". The tool being used can be asked to only include overlaps which are more than some percentage of the size of the range. By the way, the first column is the feature name, the range is the second and third columns. (I think it's inclusive.) Bernabé: You'll get much better answers if you don't assume that everyone understands the details of tools which are pretty obscure for most of us not in your field of research. I found http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html, but you could have included that URL yourself.

Comment: Thanks you guys for replying, I just added more information about the columns and the command I used in bedtools. I'm really appreciating your input!.

Comment: For the future, you should install bedtools on your local machine and learn how to use the various commands. It's a core tool in bioinformatics and working out how to get results from it in the format you want is going to be much easier than writing your own code every time.

Comment: Is there a problem with the bedtools command I posted?. IntersectBed was useful for knowing the the overlapping segments for each event when the file have thousands of intervals, and then I'm trying to consolidate. I use bedtools on a regular basis, but I'm not a programmer per se, so that's why I'm asking for help, and off course you are not going to do my PhD, as you said, with this.

Comment: I've never used bedtools myself (I'm on the software dev side of things) so I don't know. :)  Do you know about Biostars and seqanswers? Most things in bioinf. have been done before, so it's likely that someone else has already got scripts written that perform the functions you want or they can tell you the appropriate way to get what you want from bedtools.

Comment: Yes, I do know about Biostars and seqanswers and before I have
decided to post this question I've checked these and other related forums, also papers with CNV software but none of these addressed this problem the way I posted. The knowledge about CNV are recent compared with SNP and other structural variations, so is not easy to find vast examples of how to manage that kind of data, that's why I made the toy datasets to present it as a text file managing problem, in order to broaden the spectrum of people that can help.

Comment: It is probably worth posting to those other forums if you haven't done already in case anyone has done this--or you might find someone else who is interested in getting the same kinds of results who could also benefit from your script. You should probably link to this post so that others can see what has been suggested and use it as a base for further work if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the columns have the following meanings:

- col 1: chromosome number
- col 2: start position of genomic region
- col 3: end position of genomic region
- col 4: text identifier

This script looks for the areas of overlap between the named regions. It assumes that the input text is sorted by col 1 then col 2. I have put the input text in a string, but you will probably be reading it in from a file (and outputting your data to a file, too). I will leave you to work out how to do that--it is pretty easy, and there is lots of documentation on the perl website.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10";
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = '1   1   10  A
1   3   12  B
1   7   15  C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E
1   37  45  F
1   50  60  G
1   50  65  H
2   1   10  I
2   3   12  J
2   7   15  K
2   20  30  L
2   35  45  M
2   37  45  N
2   50  60  O
2   50  65  P
';

# we have tab-delimited data.
# split on line breaks, remove line ending, split on tabs
my @lines = map { chomp; [ split(/\t/, $_) ]; } split("\n", $text);

my $col_0 = 1;
my $min = 0;
my $max = 0;
my @range;

foreach (@lines) {
    # the chromosome number has changed or
    # minimum is greater than current maximum:
    # start a new interval
    if ($col_0 != $_->[0] || $_->[1] > $max) {
        if (@range) {
            # print out the range, and restart the stack
            say join("\t",
                $col_0,
                ( $min || $_->[1] ),
                ( $max || $_->[2] ),
                join(", ", @range)
            );
        }
        @range = ( $_->[3] );
        # set the min and max
        $col_0 = $_->[0];
        $min = $_->[1];
        $max = $_->[2];
    }
    else {
    # the minimum is lower than our current maximum.
    # check whether the max is greater than our current
    # max and increase it if so. Add the letter to the
    # current range.
        if ($_->[2] > $max) {
            $max = $_->[2];
        }
        push @range, $_->[3];
    }
}
# print out the last line
say join("\t", $col_0, $min, $max, join(", ", @range) );
```

Output:

```
1   1   15  A, B, C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E, F
1   50  65  G, H
2   1   15  I, J, K
2   20  30  L
2   35  45  M, N
2   50  65  O, P
```

I have just calculated simple overlap - this doesn't do 50% overlap. Using this script as a start, you can figure out how to do that. We're not doing your PhD for you! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, off course I will look into the overlap % and adjust for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
$2 > end && NR>1 { 
    print "1", start, end, pair; 
    start=end=pair=0 
} 
{ 
    if (!start) { start = $2 }; 
    end = $3; 
    pair = (pair ? pair "," $4 : $4)
}
END {
    print "1", start, end, pair
}' file

1  1 15 A,B,C
1 20 30 D
1 35 45 E,F
1 50 65 G,H
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ordered data, the following stub should handle merging the records.

Would just have to modify it to load and output to a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(min max);

my $last;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;

    if ( !$last ) {
        $last = \@fields;

    } elsif ( $last->[0] == $fields[0] && $last->[2] > $fields[1] ) {
        $last->[1] = min( $last->[1], $fields[1] );
        $last->[2] = max( $last->[2], $fields[2] );
        $last->[3] .= ",$fields[3]";

    } else {
        print join( "\t", @$last ), "\n";
        $last = \@fields;
    }
}

print join( "\t", @$last ), "\n";

__DATA__
1   1   10  A
1   3   12  B
1   7   15  C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E
1   37  45  F
1   50  60  G
1   50  65  H
2   1   10  I
2   3   12  J
2   7   15  K
2   20  30  L
2   35  45  M
2   37  45  N
2   50  60  O
2   50  65  P
```

Outputs:

```
1   1   15  A,B,C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E,F
1   50  65  G,H
2   1   15  I,J,K
2   20  30  L
2   35  45  M,N
2   50  65  O,P
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '
  function emit() {print chrom, start, end, annot}
  $1 == chrom && ((start<=$2 && $2<=end) || (start<=$3 && $3<=end)) {
    annot = annot "," $4
    if ($2 < start) start = $2
    if ($3 > end) end = $3
    next
  }
  chrom {emit()}
  {chrom=$1; start=$2; end=$3; annot=$4}
  END {emit()}
' file1
```

```
1   1   15  A,B,C
1   20  30  D
1   35  45  E,F
1   50  65  G,H
```